# Random integer in go language are predictable in each runtime

Tags: go, random, integer

I'm using `math/rand` package to generate random integer number as temporary tokens. The problem is the random numbers are predictable (same sequence always) in each runtime. I've even used `Seed()` function before calling `rand.Intn(100000)` but those numbers are also predictable.
Is there a way to generate truly random numbers in `Golang`? By the way here is my final code.

```
rand.Seed(rand.Intn(500))
fmt.Println(rand.Intn(100000))
```

Comment: The seed determines the starting point of a PRNG. If you don't change it, then the sequence of numbers won't change either. The crypto/rand package has a PRNG that doesn't require seeding. You need [hardware](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) for true randomness.

Comment: @Peter does the accepted answer provides what I need in software level?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't said what you need. Random numbers are just means to an end. It's impossible to tell if math/rand is good enough (with a varying seed, of course), or if crypto/rand is the better choice.

Comment: thank you @Peter. I'm using the accepted answer and since all I need is not guessable numbers in each runtime I think that is enough for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.Nanoseconds()` as the seeder. It gives you more randomness but as [effective go](https://github.com/golovers/effective-go) stated, using `math/rand` seeded with `time.Nanoseconds()` leads to just a few bits of entropy.
As an alternative you can use what solution effective go is using (`crypto/rand` package) but here is another soltion that is pseudo random.

```
import (
    crand "crypto/rand"
    "math/rand"
)

type cryptSrc struct{}

func (s cryptSrc) Seed(seed int64) {}

func (s cryptSrc) Int63() int64 {
    return int64(s.Uint64() & ^uint64(1<<63))
}

func (s cryptSrc) Uint64() (v uint64) {
    err := binary.Read(crand.Reader, binary.BigEndian, &v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return v
}

// Generate a truly random number
func RandomInt64(i int64) int64 {
    var src cryptSrc
    rnd := rand.New(src)
    return rnd.Int63n(i)
}
```

You can use `RandomInt64` function where ever you want and be certain that the generated number is pseudo random.